# change woocommerce redirect URL after payment cancellation

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I noticed that my Woocommerce checkout process does not return the customer to the checkout page after a payment is cancelled, instead he is redirected to the home page.

Specifics:
I use a Wordpress site where a customer can pay with Paypal, creditcard etc. Both Paypal and my creditcard setup require the website to redirect to an external site to do the payment and when the payment is complete, the customer is directed back to the order-received page. This is all working fine.

But if the customer on the external site (Paypal.com for example) decides to hit the "cancel payment" he arrives back to the home page with a URL like this: https://example.com/?cancel_order=true&order=wc_order_oEYInB5bC3mCo&order_id=225487&redirect&_wpnonce=99cfb8ef9f

I checked my site with all plugins disabled and default theme and the same thing happens. It seems to be part of Woocommerce standard setup.

I have searched for a solution but did not find anything about this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this same question on the woocommerce support forum and received assistance to fix the bug (though they did tell me that in the sandbox fresh installation this problem was not occuring).

Here is the code snippet which resolved it for me:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cancelled_order','lenura_redirect_to_home');
 function lenura_redirect_to_home() {
    wp_redirect(home_url( '/checkout/' )); // REDIRECT PATH
 }
```

In case anyone else is running into this.